# Curated Collections of Questions (as posts on Meta)

Tags: discussion

*Idea:* We can create posts on this meta site to highlight curated **collections** of interesting questions from our main site, then periodically rotate those collections through the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) box on the main site.

What kind of collections could we have? Here's a few ideas to get us started:

- What clothes do vegans wear?
- What is important in a balanced vegan diet?
- Getting enough protein (for vegans and vegetarians)
- What are the differences between veganism and lacto-ovo vegetarianism?

To keep things organized, we would probably want to introduce [collections](/questions/tagged/collections) as a new tag here on meta.

Astute readers might have noticed that Stack Overflow for Teams (the paid product) already has a feature called [collections](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/06/introducing-collections-on-stack-overflow-for-teams/), which is unfortunately not available for network sites like ours. Because we can't use real Collections here, I'm proposing this alternative to fulfill the same purpose.

#### Rationale

Recently I was thinking about how the Q&A format here on Stack Exchange really excels at drawing attention to questions that have some depth and require more expertise to answer. However, the flip side is that introductory and entry-level questions, of which there are relatively few, tend to get buried. And on most sites, that is fine!

However, **Vegetarianism & Veganism** might be different from other Stack Exchange sites because vegetarianism has a completely different learning curve. My experience with software developers is that they are faced with ever-growing complexity and nuance as they grow in their area of expertise. However, my experience meeting vegetarians and vegans is the complete opposite -- the first two years after adopting a vegan or vegetarian lifestyle are full of questions, but eventually people settle into a rhythm and the practice becomes second-nature, without much daily complexity.

As I stated [in my election nomination](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election#post-2388), I believe this site holds a lot of potential to help people who are in their first two years of exploring vegan and vegetarian lifestyles. For that reason, I think it's worth putting a bit more emphasis on ideas that could be helpful to that audience.

---

*This post is an expansion of an idea I originally [shared](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58922313#58922313) in [The Greenhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/the-greenhouse), the chat room for this site. Everyone is welcome to join the chat room -- we'd love to have you!*